# Call a Postgresql function passing an array of integer using mybatis

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, mybatis

It might be a direct question but I'm trying many options which is not working.
I've given the below details for your reference.
Mybatis xml configuration:-

```
<select id="updateComps" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.List">
  <![CDATA[ {call vivo.select_workout (#{list, mode=IN, jdbcType=ARRAY})}]]>        
</select>
```

Postgres Function:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vivo.delete_completed_activity_logged_workout(INT[])
    RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
ids ALIAS FOR $1;
dist BIGINT[];
```

Mapper config:-

```
void deleteCompletedActivityRecords(List<Integer> users);
```

Error facing:-

> aused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null
>   for parameter #1 with JdbcType ARRAY . Try setting a different
>   JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property.
>   Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot
>   be cast to java.sql.Array     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87)
>     ... 68 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.sql.Array   at
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ArrayTypeHandler.java:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:53)
>     ... 69 more [WARNING] Could not send response error 500:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for
>   mapping: ParameterMapping{property='list', mode=IN, javaType=class
>   java.lang.Object, jdbcType=ARRAY, numericScale=null,
>   resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for
>   parameter #1 with JdbcType ARRAY . Try setting a different JdbcType
>   for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be
>   cast to java.sql.Array

Comment: You need to write a custom type handler. It would look pretty much the same as this [one](https://github.com/gbif/common-mybatis/blob/266b4517a18cefccfc931bbbd80d9c61e77042bd/src/main/java/org/gbif/mybatis/type/StringArrayTypeHandler.java) except `"integer"` should be the first argument of `createArrayOf` instead of `"text"`.

Comment: Thank you. I added a custom typeHandler for integer. Based on the link you've suggested and the below one.

Comment: https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/mybatis-calls-postgresql-stored-procedures-to-implement-array-entry-parameter-delivery-_postgresql_1_44_20091735.html

Answer (score 0):

I created the below custom ArrayTypeHandler.

```
package com.lf.util;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.ARRAY)
public class CustomArrayTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<List<Long>> {
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, List<Long> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        Array array = ps.getConnection().createArrayOf("integer", parameter.toArray());
        ps.setArray(i, array);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return toList(rs.getArray(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return toList(rs.getArray(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        return toList(cs.getArray(columnIndex));
    }

    private List<Long> toList(Array pgArray) throws SQLException {
        if (pgArray == null) return Lists.newArrayList();

        Long[] strings = (Long[]) pgArray.getArray();
        return containsOnlyNulls(strings) ? Lists.<Long>newArrayList() : Lists.newArrayList(strings);
    }

    private boolean containsOnlyNulls(Long[] strings) {
        for (Long s : strings) {
            if (s != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the xml file:

```
<select id="deleteRecords" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType="java.lang.Integer" parameterType="java.util.List">
        <![CDATA[ {call vivo.delete_records (#{list, mode=IN, typeHandler=com.lf.util.CustomArrayTypeHandler})}]]>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MyBatis' script engine to build a query like this to cast your list to INT[]:

`call vivo.select_workout (ARRAY [1,2,3,4,5,6]::INT[])`

For example:

```xml
<select id="updateComps" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.List">
    {call vivo.select_workout (ARRAY <foreach item="userId" collection="users" open="[" separator="," close="]">#{userId}</foreach>::INT[]) }
</select>
```